# RollupJS: Unresolved internal dependency

Tags: rollupjs

I'm getting an error that looks like it's unable to resolve my import to my other module.

Running `rollup -c` I'm getting the following error

> (!) Unresolved dependencies
>
> https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency
>   components/main/view (imported by src\index.js)
>
> (!) Missing global variable name
>
> Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
>   C:\Users\n88040\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js (guessing 'View')

**src/index.js**

```
import View from 'components/main/view`;
View();
```

**src/components/main/view.js**

```
const View = () => console.log('foo');
export default View;
```

Comment: WOW, I feel dumb. Thank you. Please post that as the answer so I can accept and give you credit.

Comment: Don't need to feel dumb, you couldn't predict that you can't use based relatives path for rollup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#es-module-syntax

You have to import local dependencies with a leading period as otherwise it will be interpreted as an external dependency:

```
import View from './components/main/view';
```